Bedlam cube variation
I found this puzzle with no manual how to assemble it. after some investigation it was suggested to me it resembles Bedlam cube 4×4×4 but 3 of the pieces are way different.
here are all pieces:

after following a Bedlam tutorial (skipping pieces I dont have) I end up with a cube where front and back are unfinishable (the rest fits perfectly)


and these are those 3 pieces I am left with:

I do wonder if this puzzle can have more than one solution, tho.
Edit:
...in the meanwhile, the best outcome so far:


Welcome to PE ! Perhaps you can tell where you found this puzzle. Also PE etiquette is not so much about asking what you do not know as opposed to challenging others to solve what you do know. Nevertheless a reference to this puzzle would be  great input,

@FirstNameLastName I see. sadly there is no more intel I could share. not even sure how this is exactly called. it was left on a bench in Montenegro (EU)

I disagree with @FirstNameLastName. While most questions on PSE are created for users to solve, there is nothing against questions like this one. There are plenty of questions asking for help with mechanical puzzles, including burr-puzzles and disentanglement puzzles as well as polycube puzzles. There are also questions asking for the 'next step' in various logical deduction puzzles. All of these are welcome.

Thanks a lot @DanielMathias to correct me. I apologize here for having drawn a somewhat black and white picture of PE etiquette and content.

As with the two-dimensional pentominoes, there are indeed many solutions to this puzzle. A programmed search found 72,454 distinct solutions. I will post one of them on Saturday, if not sooner. Even then, I encourage you to keep trying as finding a solution is much more rewarding than assembling the cube with instruction.

It can be very difficult to find a solution by hand in a puzzle like this. One thing that increases the chances of finding one is to try to save the smallest piece for last whenever possible. This puzzle has one piece made of just 4 cubes while the rest have 5. This small piece has a higher probability of fitting in the leftover gap at the end than if you do that with a larger piece.

There are many thousands of ways to assemble the cube. Here I present one (or four) of them, piece by piece.
The first three pieces:

 
 The first two pieces together can be flipped over to create a second solution.

Four, five, six:

 

Seven, eight, nine:

 
 These three pieces can be flipped and rotated as a group.

Ten, eleven, twelve:

 

The last piece completes the cube:

 


Can you briefly sketch how you went about the computer search?

@DanielMathias indeed awesome answer, thank you. I tried all 4 of them and probably found fifth. could you spare few words on how you solved it? was it brute force, program simulation or math calculation? lastly, any idea how this puzzle is called properly?

@BenjaminWang Exhaustive search. The unit cubes are indexed 0 to 63. Beginning with 0, try each available piece in any orientation that occupies the target unit cube without intersected previously placed pieces or extending out of bounds, recursively targeting the unoccupied unit cube with the lowest index until all 13 polycubes have successfully been placed.

@puzzler0 This puzzle is not likely to have a proper name. It is clearly a variation of the Bedlam cube, but with millions of ways to choose a set of polycubes that might be assembled into a 4x4x4 cube, we cannot realistically provide distinct labels for each of them.
